# Spring Data CrudRepository cascading deletes on @OneToMany Unidirectional

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Evening all,

I have an field with the following signature:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
@JoinColumn(name="username")
private Collection<UserAuthority> authorities;
```

When I try to remove a UserAuthority from the collection, it tries updating by setting username to null, rather than deleting.

Remove:

```
...
authorities.remove(targetAuthority);
user.setAuthorities(authorities);
repo.save(user);
...
```

Is this correct?

The only way I can get it to cascade the delete correctly is if I have a seperate UserAuthority repository and do something like the following

```
...
authRepo.delete(authorities);
...
```

Any help would be awesome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have given above will work if you map this as a bi-directional relationship:

```
 @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true, mappedBy="user")   
 private Collection<UserAuthority> authorities;
```

and then in UserAuthority:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="username")
private User user;
```

MappedBy tells Hibernate that the UserAuthority is the owning entity i.e. it has the foreign key which defines the association. Therefore when you want to save a new UserAssociation entity you need to make sure that you set the User which is refers to.

This will also result in a more optimised saving process because Hibernate can insert the UserAuthority records with the correct foreign key rather than doing an insert then update to set it.

Comment: Interesting, having done almost all my work with JDBC and pure sql in Spring, Hibernate seems pretty awesome, but quiet different to get used to =)

I have a question, though, if I'm using a composite key such as username / role being the PK to the UserAuthority table, do I put the @ManyToOne relation on the composite key?

Comment: You can put the @ManyToOne on properties in your composite key.

Comment: This worked with the following addition to the UserAuthority class

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="username", insertable = false, updatable = false)
 @ForeignKey(name="FK_UA_USER")
 private User user;